# How to switch the code from Select Range (Input Box) to Row Count?

Tags: excel, vba

Current Code is provided below. The user selects the Range of cells from which unique values needs to be found out. Instead of this, I know the Range of cells which is entire Column B of Sheet Database. I tried switching the code by the code below but it's giving "Run-time error '424': Object Required" where I am trying to count the number of rows with data.

```
Sheets("Database").Activate

last_row = Cells(Row.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row         <- Error 

Set rngTarget = Sheets("Database").Range("B2:B" & last_row)
If rngTarget Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Current Code:

```
strPrompt = "Select the Range from which you'd like to extract uniques"
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rngTarget = Application.InputBox(strPrompt, "Get Range", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngTarget Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

Changed Code: (Doesn't work - Gives Run-Time Error)

```
Sheets("Database").Activate

last_row = Cells(Row.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row         <- Error 

Set rngTarget = Sheets("Database").Range("B2:B" & last_row)
If rngTarget Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

rngTarget function should contain the range of cells from which unique values needs to be found out.

Update 1
Complete Code for reference:

```
Public Sub WriteUniquesToNewSheet()

    Dim wksUniques As Worksheet
    Dim rngUniques As Range, rngTarget As Range
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim varUniques As Variant
    Dim lngIdx As Long
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim colUniques As Collection
    Set colUniques = New Collection

    'Prompt the user to select a range to unique-ify
    'strPrompt = "Select the Range from which you'd like to extract uniques"
    'On Error Resume Next
    '    Set rngTarget = Application.InputBox(strPrompt, "Get Range", Type:=8)
    'On Error GoTo 0
    'If rngTarget Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<~ in case the user clicks Cancel

    Sheets("Database").Activate

    last_row = Cells(Row.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Rows

    Set rngTarget = Sheets("Database").Range("B2:B" & last_row)
    If rngTarget Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Collect the uniques using the function we just wrote
    Set colUniques = CollectUniques(rngTarget)

    'Load a Variant array with the uniques
    '(in preparation for writing them to a new sheet)
    ReDim varUniques(colUniques.Count, 1)
    For lngIdx = 1 To colUniques.Count
        varUniques(lngIdx - 1, 0) = CStr(colUniques(lngIdx))
    Next lngIdx

    'Create a new worksheet (where we will store our uniques)
    Set wksUniques = Worksheets("Lists")

    Set rngUniques = wksUniques.Range("A2:A" & colUniques.Count + 1)
    rngUniques = varUniques

    'Let the user know we're done!
    MsgBox "Finished!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Row.Count` into `Rows.Count`. But also, for future reference, you can avoid using `.Activate`, rather specify which worksheet you working from, e.g.: `With Thisworkbook.Sheets("Database") ......code...... End with`

Comment: @JvdV it worked. Thank you for the prompt support.

Comment: FWIW "Object Required" is because you haven't specified `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, making your code vulnerable to silly things, like typos. `Row` is undefined, but without `Option Explicit` it's happily an on-the-fly `Variant/Empty` variable - but you can't make a `.Count` member call against a `Variant/Empty`, *an object is required*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, you have refered to [`Row`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row) instead of a range object representing all [`Rows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.rows). Follow the links to see the difference :)

Next you have used `.Activate` and therefor not specified what worksheet you working from. A better practice would be to use something like:

```
With Thisworkbook.Sheets("Database") 'Can even be dereferenced from worksheets collection
    last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 
    Set rngTarget = .Range("B2:B" & last_row) 'Tricky if last_row is 1
    If rngTarget Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Superfluous and can be deleted
End with
```

Comment: Even better: dereference the sheet from the  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` collection. Better still: give that sheet a code name (say, `DbSheet`) and go `With DbSheet`. Also `rngTarget` can't possibly be `Nothing` (assuming the sheet exists), so that last `If` condition is superfluous.

Comment: @KshitijChhikara ALL recommendations in this answer are on point.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, true, and one more thing, if last_row would be 1 (for whatever reason) OP will end up with a range of `$B$1:$B$2`. Thanks for the constuctive input!